# How to take T out of Result<Vec<Data<&T>>>?

Tags: rust, reference, channel, ownership, rust-result

I'd like to take `SomeType` out of `Result<Vec<Data<&SomeType>>>`, and then pass it by a channel, but I failed:

```
pub fn read(result: Result<Vec<Data<&SomeType>>, ()>, tx: mpsc::Sender<SomeType>) {
    if let Ok(datas) = result {
        for data in datas.iter() {
            let actual_data = data.value();
            let some_type_instance = SomeType { k: 1 };
            tx.send(some_type_instance); // works
            tx.send(**actual_data); // errors
        }
    }
}
```

errors with:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `**actual_data` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:40:21
   |
40 |             tx.send(**actual_data);
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `**actual_data` has type `SomeType`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

It seems that `tx` didn't take the ownership correctly. Although implementing the `Copy` trait on `SomeType` can eliminate the error, I am not sure if `Copy` or `Clone` would reduce the performance. I am struggling with it but couldn't find a correct way to fix it.

**The following is a complete code to regenerate the error.**

```
use std::result::Result;
use std::sync::mpsc;

pub struct SomeType {
    k: i32,
}

pub struct Data<D> {
    value: D,
}

impl<D> Data<D> {
    pub fn value(&self) -> &D {
        &self.value
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let a = SomeType { k: 1 };
    let b = SomeType { k: 2 };
    let c = SomeType { k: 3 };

    let A = Data { value: &a };
    let B = Data { value: &b };
    let C = Data { value: &c };

    let datas = vec![A, B, C];

    let result = Ok(datas);
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    read(result, tx);
}

pub fn read(result: Result<Vec<Data<&SomeType>>, ()>, tx: mpsc::Sender<SomeType>) {
    if let Ok(datas) = result {
        for data in datas.iter() {
            let actual_data = data.value();
            let some_type_instance = SomeType { k: 1 };
            tx.send(some_type_instance); // this line works
            tx.send(**actual_data); // this line errors
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you tried can't work because you cannot have a `T` value in two places at the same time. In other words, you can't keep `T` in a `Data` _and_ return it from `Data::data()`. The correct solution will depend on what exactly you want to do. Without knowing the details, I can recommend holding `Arc<T>` in `Data` and having `data()` return `Arc<T>` implemented as `return Arc::clone(&self.value)`. You should be able to send the `Arc` through the channel.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you. Is there a way only by changing the body of `fn read()`, since in my actual application, result is obtained by calling an imported external crate. If I cannot have a `T` value in two places at the same time, as you mentioned, is it possible to destroy the first place and let the second place take ownership?

Comment: If you control the `T` with which you construct `Data<T>`, then it is possible. One thing you have to make sure is that the value inside `Data` _remains valid_ after you extract `SomeType` out of it. A simple and effective way of achieving that is by using `Option<SomeType>`. An option allows you to take the value it holds and leave `None` in its place, leaving the option in a different but valid state. The option type even has a `take()` method which does just that, but requires a mutable reference. Which brings us to the other issue, that of `Data::read()` returning a shared reference...

Comment: You can work around `Data::read()` returning `&T` by using interior mutability, i.e. `RefCell<Option<SomeType>>` (don't be put off by the nested generics, just read them as "refcell containing optional SomeType"). `RefCell` has a `borrow_mut()` method giving you a mutable reference to the inner content, on which you can then call `Option::take()` - or you can call `RefCell::take()` which will do the right thing by itself. [Here is working code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e06aa8172b80aedd119211d2e4d8385), with other minor aesthetic changes.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for your help. It has increased my knowledge and really helps in understanding the mechanism.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes, please, that couldn't be any better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all you have is a `&T`, you cannot get a `T` without cloning the value behind the reference, because extracting a non-copy value would *move* it, and the owner of the `T` (here `Data`) who gave out the reference expects the value to remain valid.

However, if you control the type stored into `Data`, you can wrap your actual value in an `Option`. Then you can use `std::mem::replace(ref_to_t, None)` to obtain the value behind the reference and leave `None` in its place. `Option` even has a [`take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) method that does that for you.

But both `mem::replace()` and `Option::take()` require a mutable reference, and all you have is a shared reference. To work around that, you need to also use interior mutability, such as provided by [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html). The type you will then put in `Data` is `RefCell<Option<SomeType>>` - don't be put off by the nested generics, just read them as "`RefCell` containing an optional `SomeType`"). `RefCell` has a `borrow_mut()` method giving you a mutable reference to the inner content, on which you can then call `Option::take()`, or you can call `RefCell::take()` which will do the right thing by itself.

```
pub fn main() {
    let a = SomeType { k: 1 };
    let b = SomeType { k: 2 };
    let c = SomeType { k: 3 };

    let da = Data {
        value: RefCell::new(Some(a)),
    };
    let db = Data {
        value: RefCell::new(Some(b)),
    };
    let dc = Data {
        value: RefCell::new(Some(c)),
    };

    let datas = vec![da, db, dc];

    let (tx, _rx) = mpsc::channel();
    read(&datas, tx);
}

pub fn read(datas: &[Data<RefCell<Option<SomeType>>>], tx: mpsc::Sender<SomeType>) {
    for data in datas {
        let actual_data = data.value().take().unwrap();
        tx.send(actual_data).unwrap();
    }
}
```